# Does the List<Object> returned by org.jooq.Query.getBindValues() contain type-safe objects - for each query parameter?

Tags: java, jpa, types, jooq

New to JOOQ.
Came across this post:
https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-jooq-a-match-made-in-heaven/

`

```
SelectConditionStep<Record3<String, String, String>> jooqQuery = 
        ctx.select(AUTHOR.FIRSTNAME, AUTHOR.LASTNAME, BOOK.TITLE)
            .from(AUTHOR)
                .leftJoin(BOOK_AUTHOR).on(AUTHOR.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHORS_ID))
                .leftJoin(BOOK).on(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOKS_ID.eq(BOOK.ID))
            .where(AUTHOR.FIRSTNAME.like("Thor%"));
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(jooqQuery.getSQL());
setBindParameterValues(q, jooqQuery);


private static void setBindParameterValues(javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery, org.jooq.Query jooqQuery) {
    List<Object> values = jooqQuery.getBindValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        jpaQuery.setParameter(i + 1, values.get(i));
    }
}
```

`

The method `jpaQuery.setParameter()` itself is not-type-safe as it accepts 'Object'.

**Question:** Does `jooqQuery.getBindValues()` return `List<Object>` which are "*type-safe for each-param*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is the glue code the author of the blog post wrote to convert a jOOQ `Query`  to a JPA `Query`. There is no type safety in this glue code. The type safety you are looking for was provided in other examples of the post, where the author constructed type safe queries using the jOOQ API, such as this:

```java
// This stuff is type safe
var jooqQuery = 
        ctx.select(AUTHOR.FIRSTNAME, AUTHOR.LASTNAME, BOOK.TITLE)
            .from(AUTHOR)
                .leftJoin(BOOK_AUTHOR).on(AUTHOR.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHORS_ID))
                .leftJoin(BOOK).on(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOKS_ID.eq(BOOK.ID))
            .where(AUTHOR.FIRSTNAME.like("Thor%"));

// This stuff isn't, and there is no need
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(jooqQuery.getSQL());
setBindParameterValues(q, jooqQuery);
```

Comment: "This stuff isn't, and there is no need" - what does that mean? We don't need to worry about type-safety at this point? Is it being taken care while building the SQL via JOOQ DSLContext?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking here

Comment: Thanks, as you've already answered in [twitter](https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/1232220894921154561?s=20).

And accepting your answer:

`"The type of the bind value will be printed, e.g. Integer, String, Date, etc."`